# Quantum channels, question 2: tensor products and composition of functions

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, it.information-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

Please be kind.  I've been working on this for a long time and can't find an answer.  Feel free to edit for clarity if you think the question can be better worded.

**Background**

It may help to see a previous question I asked [about quantum channels](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13581/quantum-channels-as-categories-question-1) in order to understand the basis for this question.

A quantum channel is a mapping between algebras of bounded linear operators on Hilbert spaces, $\Phi : L(\mathcal{H}_{A}) \to L(\mathcal{H}_{B})$, where $L(\mathcal{H}_{i})$ is the family of operators on $\mathcal{H}_{i}$.  In general, we are interested in completely positive, trace-preserving (CPTP) maps.  The operator spaces can be interpreted as $C^{*}$-algebras (with the involution being the standard Hilbert space adjoint, denoted by $\dagger$) and thus we can also view the channel as a mapping between $C^{*}$-algebras, $\Phi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$.  Since quantum channels can carry classical information as well, we could write such a combination as $\Phi : L(\mathcal{H}_{A}) \otimes C(X) \to L(\mathcal{H}_{B})$ where $C(X)$ is the space of continuous functions on some set $X$ and is also a $C^{*}$-algebra.  In other words, whether or not classical information is processed by the channel, it (the channel) is a mapping between $C^{*}$-algebras.  Note, however, that these are not necessarily the same $C^{*}$-algebras.  Since the channels are represented by square matrices, the input and output $C^{*}$-algebras must have the same dimension, $d$ (i.e. physicists will often "cheat" and refer to the dimension of an $n\times n$ matrix as simply $n$).  Thus we can consider them both subsets of some $d$-dimensional $C^{*}$-algebra, $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}$. Thus a quantum channel is a mapping from $\mathcal{C}$ to itself.

A quantum channel may be written as a Kraus decomposition,

$T(\rho) = \sum_{i}A_{i}\rho A_{i}^{\dagger}$

where the $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$ are the Kraus operators (and square matrices) and where

$\sum_{i}A_{i}^{\dagger}A_{i}=\textbf{1}$

and $T(\textbf{1})=\textbf{1}$.

Suppose we have two quantum channels, $r$ and $t$

$\begin{eqnarray*}
r: \rho \to \sigma &
\qquad \textrm{where} \qquad &
\sigma=\sum_{i}A_{i}\rho A_{i}^{\dagger} \\
t: \sigma \to \tau &
\qquad \textrm{where} \qquad &
\tau=\sum_{j}B_{j}\sigma B_{j}^{\dagger} 
\end{eqnarray*}$

where the $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$ and $\left\{B_{i}\right\}$ are the Kraus operators for the channels respectively.  We form the composite $t \circ r: \rho \to \tau$ where

$\begin{align}
\tau & = \sum_{j}B_{j}\left(\sum_{i}A_{i}\rho A_{i}^{\dagger}\right)B_{j}^{\dagger} \notag \\
& = \sum_{i,j}B_{j}A_{i}\rho A_{i}^{\dagger}B_{j}^{\dagger} \\
& = \sum_{k}C_{k}\rho C_{k}^{\dagger} \notag
\end{align}$

where $i \cdot j = k$.  Since $A$ and $B$ are summed over separate indices the trace-preserving property is maintained, i.e. $\sum_{k} C_{k}^{\dagger}C_{k}=\textbf{1}$.

**Core argument**

From above, we note that

$\tau=\sum_{i,j}B_{j}A_{i}\rho A_{i}^{\dagger}B_{j}^{\dagger}$.

Suppose we only have two Kraus operators for each, i.e. $A_{1}, A_{2}, B_{1}, B_{2}$.  Then

$\tau=B_{1}A_{1}\rho A_{1}^{\dagger}B_{1}^{\dagger} + B_{2}A_{1}\rho A_{1}^{\dagger}B_{2}^{\dagger} + B_{1}A_{2}\rho A_{2}^{\dagger}B_{1}^{\dagger} + B_{2}A_{2}\rho A_{2}^{\dagger}B_{2}^{\dagger}$.

($\tau$ of course has a matrix representation (in fact it is a square matrix representation).  The following has nothing to do with the size of the matrix representation of $\tau$ and only has to do with the terms in the above summation.)

Using the subscripts as a guide, I can make a matrix

$\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{c c}
B_{1}A_{1}\rho A_{1}^{\dagger}B_{1}^{\dagger} & B_{1}A_{2}\rho A_{2}^{\dagger}B_{1}^{\dagger} \\[8pt]
B_{2}A_{1}\rho A_{1}^{\dagger}B_{2}^{\dagger} & B_{2}A_{2}\rho A_{2}^{\dagger}B_{2}^{\dagger} \\[8pt]
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation*}$

This just happens to be the same dimension as the matrix representation of $\sigma \otimes \rho$.  If I then do repeated composition I get,

$\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{c c c}
B_{1}A_{1}\rho A_{1}^{\dagger}B_{1}^{\dagger} & B_{1}A_{2}\rho A_{2}^{\dagger}B_{1}^{\dagger} & \cdots \\[8pt]
B_{2}A_{1}\rho A_{1}^{\dagger}B_{2}^{\dagger} & B_{2}A_{2}\rho A_{2}^{\dagger}B_{2}^{\dagger} & \cdots \\[8pt]
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation*}$

The next step is simply to clarify the purpose.  Suppose now that I take the output of a quantum channel and feed it back in on itself.  In this case, $\left\{A_{i}\right\}=\left\{B_{i}\right\}$.  Thus if we repeatedly apply the same channel $n$ times,

$\begin{equation}
T(\rho) \circ T(\rho) \circ \cdots \circ T(\rho) = \sum_{i^{n}}(A_{i})^{n}\rho (A_{i}^{\dagger})^{n}
\end{equation}$

we can take the terms of this expansion, form a matrix out of it, and that matrix (which may or may not have any physical significance) turns out to have the same dimension as the matrix representation of,

$T(\rho) \otimes T(\rho) \otimes \cdots \otimes T(\rho) = \bigotimes^{n}_{i=1} T(\rho)$.

Physically, the last equation is like applying $n$ copies of a channel simultaneously.  In other words, there may be some kind of strange physical link between applying $n$ copies of a channel *simultaneously* and applying them in succession.

> **Questions in brief summary:** Basically (and you can read the specific questions below) I need to know if a) the math for the core argument is right and b) what the immediate algebraic implications of it are (if there are any).
>
> **Question 1:** The obvious question is, is this right, i.e. does the composition of quantum channels really have a representation that is morphic to a tensor product of quantum channels of a certain dimension (or is this obvious to a pure mathematician)?  Is this generally true at the level of category theory?
>
> **Question 2:** If it is right, the question that naturally follows is, what are the immediate algebraic implications (if any)?
>
> > **Sub-question 2a:** What kind of morphism is this on the level of monoids and/or categories, i.e. is it an isomorphism, epimorphism, etc.?

Comment: I don't understand what's a space and what's a linear transformation in your notation.  Could you clean it up a little?  

Comment: OK, I copied in my description of quantum channels from my other question and clarified a point about dimension.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Since it is hard for me to parse this question, I will arrogantly assume that it is hard for many other MOers as well.  I am going to ask some questions in the interest of clarification.  I am not an expert on quantum anything.  It is fairly well-established here on MO that if you think your question is clear enough to an expert, you need not clarify it to the point where it makes sense to a general mathematical audience.  But if you're looking to get more answers than you have, such clarification will increase the number of people who might be able to help you.

Comment: 1. You say a quantum channel is "a map between Hilbert spaces" but as written the source and target are not Hilbert spaces, but algebras of bounded linear operators on Hilbert spaces: in particular $C^*$-algebras.  Is this a mistake?

2. Does CPTP mean "completely positive trace-preserving"?  What's a good online reference for such operators?  

3. You say "the operator spaces can be interpreted as $C^*$-algebras".  This sounds vague.  Do you just mean in the usual way, i.e., with the involution being given as the Hilbert space adjoint?

4. Does $\dagger$ here mean the Hilbert space adjoint?  

Comment: 5. "note that this is a somewhat non-standard way to talk about it, but it is a relic of the fact that we're really talking about Hilbert spaces in a more general manner, i.e. it makes sense to a physicist"

I don't understand this sentence at all, neither what you mean by talking about Hilbert spaces in a general manner, nor why that would make sense to a physicist (rather than a mathematician, presumably).

Comment: 6.  "Since quantum channels can carry classical information as well, we could write such a combination as $\Phi: L(\mathcal{H}_A) \otimes C(X) \rightarrow L(\mathcal{H}_B)$  where $C(X)$ is the space of continuous functions on some set $X$ and is also a $C^*$-algebra." 

Do you mean that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space?  (Or is it just a finite set, so we may take the discrete topology?) I don't understand the mathematical relation between these two Phi's.




Comment: 7. "Since the channels are represented by square matrices..." I don't see how this makes sense without some finiteness assumptions on the Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_i$ and the set $X$: what are your assumptions here?

Comment: 8. "Thus we can consider them both subsets of some d-dimensional C-algebra $\mathcal{C}$.  Thus a quantum channel is a mapping from $\mathcal{C}$ to itself."

I don't follow.  You have a map from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ and you choose some $\mathcal{C}$ containing both.  How does this give you a map from $\mathcal{C}$ to itself?  

Comment: Well Pete, those are quite a few questions and I won't have time to answer them all before this afternoon.  But I can say, briefly, that the way I've described it is pretty much the standard way we describe these things in quantum information circles.  So I'm pretty sure I won't even be able to answer some of your questions.  But the question seemed clear enough to get a very useful response from Matt Daws (see below).

Comment: OK, in response to your first five questions, I've made clarifying corrections to the question itself.  Regarding 6,I'm not sure I understand the question.  What two phis are you talking about?  Regarding question 7, those aren't my words.  It's standard in my field to use square matrices to represent these things.  Regarding 8, a mapping from a subset of something to a different subset of the same thing, to me (and to a lot of other people), is a mapping from the larger set to itself.

Comment: Regarding the statement in question 6, I was lost completely at "such a combination".  As far as I could tell, you haven't specified what the combination was supposed to be.   Perhaps I don't know enough physics to get anything from the clause "Since quantum channels can carry classical information as well".  From my reading, you had one map \Phi between C^* algebras A, B and then this new map \Phi between L(H_A) \otimes C(X), L(H_B) which you define in that statement, and like Pete L. Clark I couldn't connect the two maps. ...

Comment:  Maybe it would help to explain what X represents? Or maybe not, skimming the rest of the question I couldn't see where the you were using the information from that paragraph. Here're some points which might help clarify the situation for me. Is d the dimension of your Hilbert spaces? Could you give a simple nontrivial explicit example of a quantum channel and its Kraus decomposition? Otherwise, could you point us to an easily accessible online reference for these topics?

Comment: @ID: As I said in my first comment, if you feel like what you have written is clear enough for some expert to understand, you need not clarify it for the majority of readers of the site.  It seems to me that you do not enjoy explaining yourself and you resist the use of standard mathematical language.  So perhaps you should just leave the question as it is and let the smaller group of people who speak your language answer your question: there's nothing wrong with that.  

Comment: @Pete: Just wondering if you can comment without making subtle, snide asides.  I do enjoy explaining.  In fact, it's my passion and, quite frankly, I'm usually pretty good at it (I may be a mediocre or even bad mathematician, but I'm a hell of a teacher).  I am using the notation that I am familiar with, some of which comes out of math books.  Since I work in physics, that's what I know.  It would be infinitely more helpful if, instead of simply pointing out all the ways in which I'm an amateur in your mind, you actually tried to teach me a little something.

Comment: @Pete: As an example of the types of constructive comments that don't have a nasty or condescending overtone, I found those of jc much more palatable.  Also note that Matthew Daws, who gave me an answer to this question, is a mathematician apparently (I don't know him personally) but didn't seem to have too much trouble figuring out what it was I was talking about.

Comment: @ID: None of my comments were snide.  All of them were meant to be helpful.  I can't even try to teach/help you until I understand what you're talking about.  Do you perhaps think that we're affecting a lack of understanding?  We're not: we're really trying as hard as we can.  Since you seem to get offended by everything I say, I don't think I can be of any help to you.  I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @Pete: Regarding your question 7, my understanding is that physicists commonly use the term "matrix" to mean a linear transformation between arbitrary Hilbert spaces, e.g. "matrix mechanics."

Comment: @QY: There's actually another definition for the word "matrix" in mathematics?

Comment: @Ian: When mathematicians use the word "matrix," they almost always mean the matrix of a linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces relative to a basis of each.  One occasionally encounters "infinite matrices," e.g. in combinatorics, but these are explicitly labeled as such.  

Comment: One problem with tossing around the word "matrix" in the infinite-dimensional context is that it really only makes sense for a linear transformation between separable Hilbert spaces (in the sense that one can write down "components" in the usual way); in the non-separable case or in the case of arbitrary infinite-dimensional vector spaces it seems to me to be better not to think componentwise since, for example, the product of two "infinite matrices" is not necessarily well-defined.

Comment: Qiaochu, I don't see the problem. Infinite matrices with respect to a basis are fine to multiply.  In the algebraic case the matrices (wrt a Hamel basis) are "column finite", and in the (possibly unseparable) Hilbert space case the matrices wrt an orthonormal basis still have "columns" and "rows" in $l^2$.  Composition of linear (respectively, continuous linear) maps corresponds to matrix multiplication.

Comment: Right, but the naive definition of matrix (an array of numbers) fails to make sense because the column-finite condition is not built in, and one needs uncountably many "rows" and "columns" with respect to an orthonormal basis in a non-separable Hilbert space.  All of which, I think, are good reasons to prefer the abstract point of view and not to use the word "matrix" for this more general concept.  This is, as far as I can tell, the standard usage of "matrix" in mathematics (as far as Wikipedia and Mathworld are concerned).

Comment:   I agree that the column-finite condition isn't built into the definition of a matrix of numbers, the latter being (plausibly) a scalar valued function on X x X, where X is an indexing set. However, if you say that M is the matrix of a linear transformation T wrt a basis {v_j} indexed by X, you don't need column finite built in, because it follows from what that means: M(i,j) = the coefficient of v_i in the basis expansion of T(v_j).

Comment: There are of course good reasons to avoid bases. My disagreement is with the statement that the multiplication doesn't make sense or isn't well-defined. For arbitrary matrices that is true, but in the context of matrices of linear transformations, which is how I interpreted your comment, it isn't. Sorry if I misinterpreted what you meant; we could just be talking about different things.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is "sort of".  A mathematical way to think about the "Kraus" operator is as follows.  Set C = B(H) (with H finite-dimensional if you wish).  Then, assuming the sum in the Kraus operator is finite (again, it could be infinite if you wish) then we can define a map $A:H \rightarrow H^n$ by a "column" operator $$A(x) = ( A_i^\dagger(x) )_{i=1}^n\qquad (x\in H).$$  Then your Kraus operator is $$ T(\rho) = \sum_i A_i \rho A_i^\dagger = A^\dagger (\rho\otimes 1) A. $$  Here $\rho\otimes 1$ is the operator on $H^n$ given by applying $\rho$ to each coordinate: the notation is explained by observing that $H^n$ is the Hilbert space tensor product $H\otimes \ell^2_n$.

So, if you have another operator $S$ given by $(B_j)_{j=1}^m$ we can form $B(x) = (B_j^\dagger(x))$ and then $$ S(T(\rho)) = B^\dagger(T(\rho)\otimes 1)B = B^\dagger (A^\dagger\otimes 1)(\rho\otimes 1\otimes 1)(A\otimes 1)B = C^\dagger (\rho\otimes 1) C,$$ where $C = (A\otimes 1)B : H\rightarrow H^{nm} = H \otimes \ell^2_n \otimes \ell^2_m$.

So, you see why tensors appear.  But this is a bit different to what you had...

Comment: OK, dumb question.  In your answer, what does `$l^{2}_{n}$` represent?

Comment: Sorry: this is just an n-dimensional Hilbert space.  So $\mathbb C^n$ with the usual $\ell^2$ norm on it.

Comment: @Matt: Seeing as you seem to have done the best out of anyone here at getting what ID was getting at - your calculation is in response to Ian's Q1 right? Is it the case that the composition and the t.p., while not isomorphic, are related by some kind of "intertwine & ampliate"?

Comment: Yemon, yes, vaguely I guess.  The pure "tensor" approach would be to look at the map $(A\otimes B)$ I think, but the composition seems to lead to looking at $(A\otimes 1)B$, which is perfectly natural, but not quite "tensoring".  If you look at what Ian had originally, in his 2nd big matrix, to get the final solution, you need to sum _all_ the entries: so the fact it's arranged in a matrix at all is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 5):

I do not really follow your notation and I know close to nothing about quantum channels, but it is impossible (assuming only that $T(\rho)$ is a linear map and the symbols $\circ$ and $\otimes$ mean what they usually mean) that $$T(\rho) \circ T(\rho) \circ \cdots \circ T(\rho)$$ be the same as $$T(\rho) \otimes T(\rho) \otimes \cdots \otimes T(\rho)$$ because the domains of the two maps are of different dimension (except in the case where the domain of $T(\rho)$ is of dimension $1$...)

**LATER:** Another shot, upgraded from a comment below. If $A=\sum_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $B=\sum_{j=1}^mB_i$ are linear maps $V\to V$, with $V$ a vector space, then $$A\circ B=\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq m}}A_i\circ B_j$$ and $$A\otimes B=\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq m}}A_i\otimes B_j$$ as a direct consequence of the facts that both $\circ$ and $\otimes$ are bilinear operations. From what little I understand in the question and comments here, I think this is the 'similarity' observed...

Comment: Yes, I realize that the size of the resulting matrix in each case is completely different.  What I'm saying above is that you can take the terms from the expansion of the first and can make a matrix that just happens to have the same dimension as the tensor expansion.  And I want to know what that implies.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I'm not yet sure what ID means by $\circ$, but as you say it must not be the ordinary composition of linear maps.  (It seems to correspond to some physical juxtaposition of the same quantum channel with itself $n$ times, but I don't understand what that means.)  

Comment: I defined what I meant by $\circ$ in the question: it *is*, in fact, the ordinary composition of linear maps.  I will edit a bit for clarity again (maybe Matt, who seemed to understand what I was asking can make the question palatable to you) In answer to your question about the physicality, it amounts to taking the output of a channel and feeding it back as the input to that same channel.  I hesitate to call it a "recursive loop," but that's the analogy that popped into my head.

Comment: @ID: If $T(\rho)$ is a linear operator on a $d$-dimensional vector space $V$, then $T(\rho) \circ T(\rho)$ is also a linear operator from $V$ to itself.  After choosing a basis, if the matrix for $T(\rho)$ is $M$, then the matrix for $T(\rho) \circ T(\rho)$ is $M^2$.  Howeover, $T(\rho) \otimes T(\rho)$ is a linear operator on $V \otimes V$, a vector space of dimension $d^2$.  It is represented by a $d^2 \times d^2$ matrix given by a standard recipe, the *Kronecker product* of $M$ with itself.  Assuming $d > 1$, these two matrices have different dimensions so are obviously not the same.  

Comment: @Pete: YES, YES, YES, I KNOW THAT.  Please, please, please reread the "core argument" part.  I have added a bit of clarification but I honestly don't know how much clearer I can be.  Try to think of these things like a little peon like me does: in terms of matrices.

Comment: @ID, Pete **is** talking about matrices. 

Comment: Well, by his comment above and QY's reply, I'm not so sure anymore if mathematicians think of matrices in the same way physicists do.  In any case, let me say for what seems like the billionth time: yes, $T(\rho) \circ T(\rho)$ and $T(\rho) \otimes T(\rho)$ have different dimensions.  BUT, if you take the terms in the summation of $T(\rho) \circ T(\rho)$, you have exactly as many terms as they are elements of the matrix representation of $T(\rho) \otimes T(\rho)$ and you *always do*.  THAT is what I find puzzling.

Comment: @Ian: if $A=\sum_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $B=\sum_{j=1}^mB_j$ are linear operators, one the sum of $n$ and the other the sum of $m$ operators, then $A\circ B=\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq m}}A_i\circ B_j$, and $A\otimes B=\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq m}}A_i\otimes B_j$. This is just because both composition of linear maps and tensor product of linear maps are bilinear operations.

Comment: Well, for whatever it's worth, I understand the question now, and Mariano has just given the correct answer. 